# Присвоить значение выше прокси

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

В следующем коде прокси с get-перехватчиком в прототип (`__proto__`) объекта. Соответственно, по схеме чтения свойств в js, до перехватчика очередь доходит только в том случае, если в непосредственно в объекте такого свойства нет. После присваивания свойство появляется в объекте и до прокси дело не доходит. Это так задумано.

```js
var x = Object.create(new Proxy({}, {
  get(obj, key) {
    if (typeof key !== 'symbol') {
      console.log('Reading a nonexisting property: ' + key);
    }
  }
}));

var temp;
console.log(1, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'));

temp = x.a;
console.log(2, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'), temp);

temp = x.a;
console.log(3, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'), temp);

x.a = 12;
console.log(4, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'));

temp = x.a;
console.log(5, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'), temp);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Теперь я в этот код добавляю перехватчик `set`:

```js
var x = Object.create(new Proxy({}, {
  get(obj, key) {
    if (typeof key !== 'symbol') {
      console.log('Reading a nonexisting property: ' + key);
    }
  },
  set(obj, key, val, receiver) {
    console.log('Assigning a property: ' + key);
    Reflect.set(obj, key, val); // Inside of proxy, not outside
    //Reflect.set(receiver, key, val); // Infinite recursion
    return true;
  }
}));

var temp;
console.log(1, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'));

temp = x.a;
console.log(2, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'), temp);

temp = x.a;
console.log(3, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'), temp);

x.a = 12;
console.log(4, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'));

temp = x.a;
console.log(5, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'), temp);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Проблема в том, что не получается записать свойство в сам объект - свойство записывается либо в тот объект, который находится внутри прокси, либо всё уходит в рекурсию метода `set`. Как это можно исправить? Т. е. результат должен быть такой же, как в предыдущем сниппете, только с появлением строки `Assigning a property: a`.

PS: [Этот вопрос на английском.](//stackoverflow.com/q/46686014/4928642)

Comment: Ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46686014/4928642

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Перевод [ответа](//stackoverflow.com/a/46687842/4928642) от [@Bergi](//stackoverflow.com/users/1048572/bergi)</sup>

Для создания свойства надо воспользоваться `Object.defineProperty` (или `Reflect.defineProperty`). Просто попытка установить свойство присваиванием или `Reflect.set` будет вызывать проход по цепочке прототипов и попадать в перехватчик `set`, что приведёт к бесконечной рекурсии.

```
new Proxy({}, {
  get(target, key) {
    if (typeof key !== 'symbol') {
      console.log('Reading a nonexisting property: ' + key);
    }
  },
  set(target, key, val, receiver) {
    console.log('Assigning a property: ' + key);
    return Reflect.defineProperty(receiver, key, {
      value: val,
      writable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    });
  }
});
```

Полный пример:

```js
var x = Object.create(new Proxy({}, {
  get(obj, key) {
    if (typeof key !== 'symbol') {
      console.log('Reading a nonexisting property: ' + key);
    }
  },
  set(obj, key, val, receiver) {
    console.log('Assigning a nonexisting property: ' + key);

    return Reflect.defineProperty(receiver, key, {
      value: val,
      writable: true,
      enumerable: true,
      configurable: true
    });
  }
}));

var temp;
console.log(1, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'));

temp = x.a; // get trap
console.log(2, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'), temp);

temp = x.a; // get trap
console.log(3, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'), temp);

x.a = 12;   // set trap creates a property and sets it
console.log(4, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'));

temp = x.a; // direct read - no traps
console.log(5, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'), temp);

x.a = 42;   // direct write - no traps
console.log(6, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'));

temp = x.a; // direct read - no traps
console.log(7, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'), temp);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```

Answer (score 2):

Додумался до такого способа, но выглядит каким-то костылём:

```js
function directSet(obj, key, val) {
  var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, null);
  var res = Reflect.set(obj, key, val);
  Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, proto);
  return res;
}

var x = Object.create(new Proxy({}, {
  get(obj, key) {
    if (typeof key !== 'symbol') {
      console.log('Reading a nonexisting property: ' + key);
    }
  },
  set(obj, key, val, receiver) {
    console.log('Assigning a property: ' + key);
    console.log(directSet(receiver, key, val));
    return true;
  }
}));

var temp;
console.log(1, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'));

temp = x.a;
console.log(2, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'), temp);

temp = x.a;
console.log(3, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'), temp);

x.a = 12;
console.log(4, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'));

temp = x.a;
console.log(5, Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'a'), temp);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100vh }
```